# How to Declare Global Variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, macros, pch

I am creating an App in which I have to declare some constant as global. in Obj C I could use pch file but I don't know how to define in Swift? For Example

in Obj C .pch file if I declare

## define Red [UIColor redColor]

then it works through out application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a `Constants.swift` (or what ever you want to name it) file and then add what ever constants you need into it.

```
let myVariable = "Some Value"
let myOtherVariable = "Something Else"
```

They will then be available throughout your application.

Comment: Is this a Swift File? or any other class's subclass?

Comment: Just a normal blank swift file. You don't need to create a `struct` or `class` to create global constants.